# Python type hint on default parameter explodes

Tags: python, types

Without `: int` this program runs fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import typing  # not needed

def foo():
    return (1,2,3)

def bar(i = foo()[0]: int):  # adding ': int' breaks the Universe
    return i

print(bar())
```

Answer (score 3):

You've got it backwards, the type hint goes after the param, not after the default:

```py
def bar(i: int = foo()[0]):
```

Comment: +1 Mind bogglingly silly of me. Thanks for the debug bryh, I should start using my brain from time to time.

Comment: We're all mind-bogglingly silly sometimes :)